# ACF value into js/jquery - YouTube fullscreen video

Tags: php, jquery, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm not sure if i can ask this way, but i will try.
I use this YouTube fullscreen jquery plugin - [Link](https://github.com/rochestb/jQuery.YoutubeBackground)
The problem is that i have to enter the YouTube video ID manually in the script. How do i get my ACF value to replace the videoId?
I have tried like this

```
<script>

  var jsVideo = <?php echo get_field('hero_baggrundsvideo'); ?>;

(function($) {
  $('#heroVideo').YTPlayer({
    fitToBackground: true,
    videoId: ''.$jsVideo.''
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

But it does not work. I have placed this script inside my php file.
I hope you get what i am trying to say.
Please correct me, if my question is wrong.

Comment: I just found out that i can't run the script in my php file - then the plugin won't execute.. But if you know how to use the variable, i'll be happy to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above everything else, your JS code has syntax problems.

Dot `.` concatenates strings in PHP, Js uses `+`. You are not adding quotes around the video id. Try this and check the developer console for other errors.

```
<script>

  var jsVideo = "<?php echo get_field('hero_baggrundsvideo'); ?>";
  console.log("I am playing: "+jsVideo);

(function($) {
    $('#heroVideo').YTPlayer({
    fitToBackground: true,
    videoId: jsVideo;
 });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```